# Name Error: _gradient_descent() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter_check'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to reproduce the example for implementing the T- distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding or t-SNE algorithm from sklearn as described [here](https://github.com/oreillymedia/t-SNE-tutorial).

On running the TSNE function I get this error:

```
TypeError: _gradient_descent() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter_check'
```

Currently the t-SNE function does not have any `n_iter_check` argument so not sure what is the unexpected keyword argument.

The only online help I found was at this [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6450)

Anyone who has managed to work around this?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `sklearn` module and find related function in `tsne` for `gradient_descent`.

You will find that it has **two extra parameters that you have to initialize** in your new function. There are two missing parameters: `n_iter_check` and  `kwargs`

```
def _gradient_descent(objective, p0, it, n_iter, objective_error=None, n_iter_check=1, n_iter_without_progress=50, momentum=0.5, learning_rate=1000.0, min_gain=0.01, min_grad_norm=1e-7, min_error_diff=1e-7, verbose=0, args=None, kwargs=None):
```